# Docker-compose keyrock mysql subnet configuration

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, docker-swarm, fiware, fiware-keyrock

I have created a docker-compose file in order to deploy my FIWARE stack. That stack includes keyrock and a Mysql BD that are connected using the following subnet:

```
networks:
    default:
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 172.18.1.0/24
```

I have created that subnet due to in keyrock documentation says that keyrock use the following ip: 172.18.1.5

I would like to change that keyrock IP and also change the subnet. How can I change the subnet? If I change the subnet and the keyrock and mysql defaul IP's there is no connection between them.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the documentation you are referring to is the sample [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm/blob/master/extras/docker/docker-compose.yml) file.

```
keyrock:
    image: fiware/idm:7.8.0
    container_name: fiware-keyrock
    hostname: keyrock
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.1.5
```

This defines an I.P. Address for keyrock (172.18.1.5) which is acceptable to the MySQL Database.

```
mysql-db:
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7
    hostname: mysql-db
...
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=172.18.1.5"
```

The MySQL 5.7 [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/docker-mysql-more-topics.html) states:

> `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST`: By default, MySQL creates the `root'@'localhost`
>   account. This account can only be connected to from inside the
>   container as described in Connecting to MySQL Server from within the
>   Container. To allow root connections from other hosts, set this
>   environment variable. For example, the value 172.17.0.1, which is the
>   default Docker gateway IP, allows connections from the host machine
>   that runs the container. The option accepts only one entry, but
>   wildcards are allowed (for example, `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=172.*.*.*` or
>   `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%`)

You can amend the I.P. Address and range to values of your own choosing, provided you also keep the docker ENV variable in line as well.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. The problem is that if I change the mysql or keyrock ip, the FIWARE component (keyrock) can't create the default configurations. However, if I use the default ip configuration, when I start the services, Keyrock automatically create a table in mysql.

Comment: Keyrock creates the defaults _once it successfully connects_ to a MySQL instance. If it can't connect (or MySQL won't allow it) the default user won't be created, so failure to create means you have a connection issue. The documented I.P. address isn't a requirement , it is merely a working  example. You should probably post your existing docker compose and the keyrock connection log to get further advice.

Comment: Ok, It works fine in local(using docker-compose). However it doesn't work using docker swarm. Could you give me an example of keyrock - mysql configuration using a docker-swarm file?

Comment: Sorry, could you help me? I need to deploy it using docker stack deploy. Thanks in advanced.